# How to customize content inside Tooltip in Google Chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

[image]

I have the following `data` model for the above chart.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["", "Goal Achieved", {role: 'style'}, target_goal_annotation, {role: 'style'}, {role: 'annotation'}],
        [1, achieved_goal, "opacity: .75;", target_goal, "opacity: 0;", "" ]
    ]);
```

When I hover over the progress bar the first line is always `1` because I have `1` in the first place in above data block.

If I put anything else, the baseline disappears, which is understandable. I need to replace the `1` in the tooltip and put something else e.g. **Points collected**.

How would I achieve this with the baseline visible?

By baseline, I mean the horizontal at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default, the tooltip will use the formatted value of the data table cell.

using object notation, we can provide both the value (`v:`) and the formatted value (`f:`)

so, to display something other than `1`, use something like the following...

```
{v: 1, f: 'Points collected'}
```

e.g.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["", "Goal Achieved", {role: 'style'}, target_goal_annotation, {role: 'style'}, {role: 'annotation'}],
    [{v: 1, f: 'Points collected'}, achieved_goal, "opacity: .75;", target_goal, "opacity: 0;", "" ]
]);
```

Comment: Awesome! However, can I use chart `title` instead of a constant (`Points collected`) here @WhiteHat?

Comment: you would need to set the chart title first, then something like --> `{v: 1, f: options.title}` -- I can't remember your code, if you're using a chart wrapper, it could be something like --> `{v: 1, f: chartWrapper.getOption('title')}`